# Rubymotion Base64

Tags: ios5, rubymotion

I am looking for a simple way to encode a string using base64. In ruby motion I can't just use the Base64encode of Ruby because I am not able to require it. So I thought I could use a build in function of Cocoa. But Cocoa does not seem to have a Base64encode function. I have found some categories on NSData, but don't know how to use them in a ruby motion project. Should I create a statics library for this?

I have got the feeling that I am looking in the wrong direction, there must be easy solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the source for `Base64.encode64` method, you'll see that it just uses the `pack` method. So you can encode/decode like this (note that you need to put the thing you want to encode inside an array):

```
["my string"].pack("m")
# => "bXkgc3RyaW5n\n"

"bXkgc3RyaW5n\n".unpack("m").first
# => "my string"
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-encode64

Comment: Thanks! I use .pack["m0"] to skip the line feeds.

Comment: Yeah that would be the equivalent of Base64's `strict_encode64` method.

Comment: I think you mean to call unpack on a string, not an array. `Array#pack => String`, and `String#unpack => Array` [edited your answer]

Comment: I could have sworn that at the time (ruby 1.9.3) there was a reason I used an array and not a string, but it was probably just a typo. It's updated now, thanks!